# React router context not reaching protected route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my index.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { msalConfig } from './azureAuthConfig';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>
);
```

This is my app.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import './App.css';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import AuthRequired from './components/AuthRequired';
import Usage from "./components/Usage";
import Login from "./components/Login";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route element={<AuthRequired />} >
            <Route path="usage" element={<Usage />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter >
  );
}
```

And this is my `Layout` component where I have defined some outlet context.

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from "./Header"
import Footer from "./Footer"
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReportingPeriod, SelectedProjects } from '../types';
import { DefaultReportingPeriod } from '../utils';

export default function Layout() {
  // Set Context for the Pollination key
  const [pollinationKey, setPollinationKey] = React.useState<string>("")

  // Set reporting period to be used on the rest of the app
  const [reportingPeriod, setReportingPeriod] = React.useState<ReportingPeriod>({
    start: DefaultReportingPeriod().start,
    end: DefaultReportingPeriod().end
  });

  // Set Project names to be used on the rest of the app
  const [selectedProjects, setSelectedProjects] = React.useState<SelectedProjects>({});

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet
        context={{
          pollinationKey, setPollinationKey,
          reportingPeriod, setReportingPeriod,
          selectedProjects, setSelectedProjects
        }}
      />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

I see that I can access this context successfully on `Login` route but not on the `Usage` route which is a protected route. Why would that be?

Here's the error I get when I try to access one of the context values

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reportingPeriod' of
> '(0 ,
> react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.useOutletContext)(...)'
> as it is undefined.

I tried the following:

1. As suggested by [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context), I did create a hook on the Layout component to consume in the Usage component. Didn't work. Same result.
2. I tried taking the `Usage` route out of the protected route just to test. It worked. I was able to access the value.
3. If I use React's Context API and wrap the `BrowserRouter` with a context provider like shown below. It works.

   ```
   export default function App() {
     return (
       <AppProvider>
         <BrowserRouter>
           <Routes>
             <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
               <Route index element={<Home />} />
               <Route element={<AuthRequired />} >
                 <Route path="usage" element={<Usage />} />
               </Route>
               <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
             </Route>
           </Routes>
         </BrowserRouter >
       </AppProvider>
     );
   }
   ```

As mentioned above, I would really like to achieve this functionality using the React Router V6's outlet context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `Layout` and `AuthRequired` should be rendering `Outlets` components if implemented normally. The issue would appear to be that you are destructuring `reportingPeriod` via `useOutletContext` directly in the leaf route component, e.g. `Usage`. The `useOutletContext` hook accesses the context value of the closest ancestor `Outlet` component, e.g. the one provided by `AuthRequired`.

You can update `AuthRequired` to access any ancestor `Outlet` context and forward on down the ReactTree.

Example:

```
export default function Layout() {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet
        context={{
          pollinationKey,
          setPollinationKey,
          reportingPeriod,
          setReportingPeriod,
          selectedProjects,
          setSelectedProjects
        }}
      />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
const AuthRequired = () => {
  const context = useOutletContext(); // <-- any ancestor context value

  ... AuthRequired business logic ...

  return <someCondition>
    ? (
      <Outlet
        context={{
          ...context, // <-- shallow copy ancestor context value
          // add any new context value
        }}
      />
    ) : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            element={<AuthRequired />} // <-- consumes Layout outlet context 
          >
            <Route
              path="usage"
              element={<Usage />} // <-- consumes AuthRequired outlet context 
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter >
  );
}
```

```
const Usage = () => {
  const { reportingPeriod } = useOutletContext();

  ...
};
```